# if statement formula for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I try to create IF formula to give me these conditions :

1. $250 if type (A2) = "A" and completeness (B2) >= 100%
2. $500 if type (A2) = "B" and completeness (B2) >= 100%
3. $0 if type (A2) = "A" and completeness (B2) < 100%
4. $0 if type (A2) = "B" and completeness (B2) < 100%

Simple way to say, if the completeness is 100% or above you will get $250 for A type or $500 for B type. And get $0 if the completeness less than 100% for both type

I manage to create formula =IF(AND(A2="A",B2>=100%),250,IF(AND(A2="B",B2>=100%),500,0)), however it didn't work the way i wanted.
I'd be really grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking for Excel help, you should tag Excel.

Comment: IF(B2<100%,0,IF(A2="A",250,500))

Answer (score 0):

try:
IF(AND(A2="A",B2>=100%),250,IF(AND(A2="B",B2>=100%),500,IF(OR(AND(A2="A",B2<100%),AND(A2="B",B2<100%)),0,"")))

(note: I have not tested it myself)

Comment: Simplify this by doing a test for "A" first - that avoids the and()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest canonical form is to test if completeness is above 100% otherwise you return 0 and then test "A" or "B". It isn't specified what happens if B2 contains neither "A" nor "B" so I've left that blank:

```
 =IF(B2<100%,0,IF(A2="A",500,IF(A2="B",250,"")))
```

With more complicated logic it may help you to draw out the states so as to be able to see the simplest expression that will achieve your intentions.

Comment: Even shorter is this posted above: IF(B2<100%,0,IF(A2="A",250,500))